# How to add a fixed amount to an array of heights so that the new minimums spread evenly?

Tags: algorithm

Given an array of heights, `H`, and an amount, `A`, what is the best way to distribute `A` between `H` to maximize the minimum array value.

Example1:

`H = { 1, 3, 2, 2, 4 }`

`A = 4`

`output = { 3, 3, 3, 3, 4 }`

Example2:

`H = { 1, 3, 2, 2, 4 }`

`A = 3`

`output = { 2.66, 3, 2.66, 2.66, 4 }`

Comment: greedily give 1 to the smallest element first?

Comment: What exactly we need to minimize? The difference between max and min elements?

Comment: can amount be non integer ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple algorithm in `O(N^2)`:

```
sort(T) // In ascending order; O(N log(N))

while amount > 0:
    i := first index such that T[i] < T[i+1]   # O(log(N)) at worst if you look for it from scratch each time, or (better) in average O(1) if you keep track of the previous such i and just look at the next values like  @jdehesa does
    amount_to_add := min(T[i+1] - T[i], amount / i)  # Considering that T[N] = infinity  makes it useless to do another loop if amount is big, it's all included here
    for j <= i:
        T[j] += amount_to_add 
    amount -= i * amount_to_add
```

At worst you'll see each position for i once, and do a loop of length i, hence `O(N^2)`.

You can actually reach `O(Nlog(N))` by just storing the changes you'll have to do in a first loop, and performing the updates in a second loop:

```
sort(T) # In ascending order; O(N log(N))

lowest_value := T[0]
amount_to_add := zeros(N)  # Array containing zeros initially
while amount > 0:
    i := first index such that lowest_value < T[i+1]   # O(log(N)) at worst. In practice probably O(1) if you keep track of the previous such i
    amount_to_add[i] := min(T[i+1] - lowest_value, amount / i) # Considering that T[N] = infinity  makes it useless to do another loop if amount is big, it's all included here
    lowest_value +=  amount_to_add[i]
    amount -= i * amount_to_add[i]
amount_to_add_incremental = 0
for j=N-1 to 0:
    amount_to_add_incremental += amount_to_add[j]
    T[j] += amount_to_add += amount_to_add_incremental
```

Maybe there is something better that can efficiently compute the final value in `O(N)` and then update all elements in the array, in which case you could get `O(N)`, but you won't do better than that.

For instance if you assume that `amount` is big: if `amount >= N*max(T) - sum(T)` for instance, which only takes `O(N)` time to check, then you can directly set all values in T to `max(T) + (amount - N*max(T) + sum(T))/N`, it takes `O(N)` time. The case where `amount` is smaller is more problematic.

Comment: Nice, I've done basically the same but iterating through the list and keeping track of the previous value to avoid the `first index such that...` operation (then after the loop I distribute any remaining `amount`). The idea of storing the changes is very good.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a Python implementation (it could be more terse with NumPy or similar but anyway):

```py
def top_up(array, amount):
    if not array:
        return []
    # Sort and keep the indices
    array_sort, sort_idx = zip(*sorted(zip(array, range(len(array)))))
    array_sort = list(array_sort)
    # Take the smallest value
    v = array_sort[0]
    # Increase values from smaller to bigger
    for i in range(1, len(array_sort)):
        if amount <= 0:
            break
        if array_sort[i] == v:
            continue
        # When a different value is found increase previous to match
        increase = min((array_sort[i] - v) * i, amount)
        for j in range(i):
            array_sort[j] += increase / i
        amount -= increase
        v = array_sort[i]
    # Distribute remainder if any
    if amount > 0:
        for i in range(len(array_sort)):
            array_sort[i] += amount / len(array_sort)
    # Back to original order
    result = [0] * len(array_sort)
    for i, v in zip(sort_idx, array_sort):
        result[i] = v
    return result
```

Test:

```
top_up([1., 5., 7., 4., 3.], 6)
>>> [4.666666666666667, 5.0, 7.0, 4.666666666666667, 4.666666666666667]
```

*UPDATE:*

Here is a little improvement taking the "incremental changes storage" idea from [gdelab's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46072329/1782792):

```
def top_up(array, amount):
    if not array:
        return []
    # Sort and keep the indices
    array_sort, sort_idx = zip(*sorted(zip(array, range(len(array)))))
    array_sort = list(array_sort)
    # Take the smallest value
    v = array_sort[0]
    # Compute incremental changes
    changes = [0] * len(array_sort)
    for i in range(1, len(array_sort)):
        if amount <= 0:
            break
        if array_sort[i] == v:
            continue
        # When a different value is found increase previous to match
        increase = min((array_sort[i] - v) * i, amount)
        changes[i - 1] = increase / i
        amount -= increase
        v = array_sort[i]
    # Distribute remainder if any
    changes[-1] = amount / len(array_sort)
    # Perform the actual changes
    change = 0
    for i in reversed(range(len(changes))):
        change += changes[i]
        array_sort[i] += change
    # Back to original order
    result = [0] * len(array_sort)
    for i, v in zip(sort_idx, array_sort):
        result[i] = v
    return result
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a pseudo-code algorithm with O(n log n) complexity:

```
# array : an array of land heights
# amount : an amount of water to fill up the lowland

tmparray = array.SortHighToLow # O(n log n) here, rest is O(n)
mean = array.MeanValue
count = array.Count;

for (height in tmparray)
begin
  newmean = mean + (amount / count)
  if (height <= newmean) break
  count--
  # recalculate mean for the remaining heights
  mean = (mean * (count + 1) - height) / count
end

for (height in array)
begin
  if (height < newmean) height = newmean # shall modify array
end
```

Note that the temp array is thrown away once you got `newmean`, which suffices to even out the original array.